# ClickOnce - System.InvalidCastException While installing Windows IoT Core Dashboard

Tags: .net, installation, clickonce, failed-installation, windows-10-iot-core

I am getting the error below while trying to install Windows IoT Core Dashboard Application to my PC. It seems like this application uses ClickOnce and right after I open the setup.exe the below error occurs. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks,

PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 10.0.10586.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.6.1078.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    clr.dll             : 4.6.1080.0 built by: NETFXREL3STAGE
    dfdll.dll           : 4.6.1038.0 built by: NETFXREL2
    dfshim.dll          : 10.0.10586.0 (th2_release.151029-1700)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : iottools.blob.core.windows.net/iotdashboard/Windows10IoTCoreDashboard.application
                        Server      : Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
    Deployment Provider url     : iottools.blob.core.windows.net/iotdashboard/Windows10IoTCoreDashboard.application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : Windows10IoTCoreDashboard.application, Version=1.0.1605.20000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c3bce3770c238a49, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.
    * Trust url parameter is set.
ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of iottools.blob.core.windows.net/iotdashboard/Windows10IoTCoreDashboard.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Specified cast is not valid.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [29.05.2016 19:51:45] : Activation of https://iottools.blob.core.windows.net/iotdashboard/Windows10IoTCoreDashboard.application has started.
    * [29.05.2016 19:51:45] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
    * [29.05.2016 19:51:45] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [29.05.2016 19:51:46] System.InvalidCastException
        - Specified cast is not valid.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.VerifyRequestedPrivilegesSupport(String requestedExecutionLevel)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.

Comment: Try reducing the UAC level. That solved the problem for me on the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset your ClickOnce store by navigating to

> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0

and delete everything there. Then try to launch it again. Sometimes the folder where ClickOnce stores its files gets corrupt. There are just "cached" files for the application, your shortcuts are still valid, so next time a ClickOnce application is launched it will re-download itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But unfortunately it didn't work. I guess for right now I am just going to move on with NOOBS installer, to install windows 10 iot to my raspberry pi.